# Touch inputs do not work after restart of Android froyo with locking application

Tags: android

I have developed a locking application (kiosk mode) for Android. Its working properly on Android honeycomb and ice cream sandwich.
If I set `category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file then touch inputs not work after restating froyo 2.2 tablet.